# Refreshing store after new request

Tags: php, extjs

I have a grid which uses a store, the store takes the data from

```
proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({url: 'http:.../request.php'}),
```

On the same page I have a form.
My goal is to refresh and populate the grid with new data composed by the query from DB via php.
I have heard there is a way to do so using php and saving the data in a json file on the server (so that the store would use the file), but doesn't it make impossible for two users work simultaniously?
Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is un clear.  If you want to reload a particular store you use a similar syntax as the following:

```
StoreName.load({params:{start:0, limit:15}});
```

Comment: I want to reload particular store by proceeding php-sql suery

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can reload the grid by using

`Ext.getCmp('idOfTheGrid').getStore().reload();`